# How to convert PDF to HTML using pdf2htmlEX and Python?

Tags: python, pdf

How to convert PDF to HTML using [pdf2htmlEX](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX) and Python?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the subprocess module

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("pdf2htmlEX /path/to/foobar.pdf", shell=True)
```

It calls the executable `pdf2htmlEX`. It must be somwhere in your `$PATH`, or you can put the absolute path in the `call`

Comment: Not quite -- you want `.call(["pdf2htmlEX", "/path/to/foobar.pdf"], shell=True)`

Comment: `.call(["pdf2htmlEX", "/path/to/foobar.pdf"], shell=False)` or `.call("pdf2htmlEX /path/to/foobar.pdf", shell=True)`. The kwarg `shell` makes it possible to give the command + arguments just as if you typed it in a shell.

Comment: Yes, you're right -- although there's no reason to make it `shell=True`, because it doesn't need to be run through a shell!

Comment: No, sure. But I chose this notation to make it easier to understand for the less-experienced.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give path of file separately instead of giving it in .call function you can do this:

```
  import subprocess
 >> path = "/home/temp/abc.pdf"
 >> subprocess.call(["pdf2htmlEX" ,path], shell=False)
```